# Joining table does not accept null values. mvc5 c#

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net-mvc

i have a problem in joning table my 2 table is null '_departureItemsTableService' and '_departureTableService' and if the 2 table is null i got an error. what is the problem with my code. thanks

```
var list = (from t in tracking
                    join d in _departureItemsTableService.GetAll() on t.box_id.Trim() equals d.BoxNo.Trim() into mar from submark in mar.DefaultIfEmpty()
                    join dt in _departureTableService.GetAll() on submark.DepartureId equals dt.DepartureId into dep from depart in dep.DefaultIfEmpty()

                    select new TrackingListModel
                    { 
                        Id = t.Id,
                        Name = t.firstname_s + " " + t.lastname_s,
                        Departure = depart?.DepartureDate ?? String.Empty,
                    });
```

Comment: Were you able to find the problem?

Answer (score 0):

Can you show how the .GetAll() is implemented? This will work fine if .GetAll() service returns an empty list instead of null.

Another possible workaround would be to assign the output in a variable outside of linq and initialize with an empty list like below -

```
var dItemTable =  _departureItemsTableService.GetAll();
if (dItemTable == null)
    dItemTable = new List<DepartureItems>();
```

Then use dItemTable in in the linq

Comment: join dt in _departureTableService.GetAll() on submark?.DepartureId equals dt.DepartureId into dep from depart in dep.DefaultIfEmpty()

Comment: by adding ? in submark it works. bcoz my column is nullable

Comment: I had bad experience with linq before. It is better not to rely on linq to take care of the nullable